# listViewItem.BackColor not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm using OwnerDraw = true, i'm not able to change the BackColor of the item (i've got several SubItems also and ListView is set to **Details** view).

Comment: How are you drawing the items?

Comment: see the example in MSDN for [`OwnerDraw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx).

Comment: We need more information, how do you initialize and use a the `ListView`.

Comment: I'm trying to do it outside the DrawItem and DrawSubItem methods using Items[0].BackColor = Color.Red; PS: I'm able to change the ForeColor but no the BackColor.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this will help since the question is a little vague, but if you want to set the BackColor of SubItems you need to set `UseItemStyleForSubItems = false` on the ListViewItem.  OwnerDraw shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Before u edit the style of the ListViewSubItem, Make sure to set the listview **UseItemStyleForSubItems** property to **false**:

```
p_lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
p_lvi.SubItems[3 /*use your sub item index*/].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

**and that's all... :)**

Answer (score 0):

you can visit: [ListViewItem.BackColor Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.backcolor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I think it help to you